# SharePoint Columns not being deployed from Visual Studio inside one Feature

Tags: visual-studio, list, sharepoint, deployment

I tried deploying 7 lists inside of one Feature in a Visual Studio deployment Package.  It deployed the List Definition and Instances but only filled them with the default columns.

Any columns I specified in the List Definition were not deployed.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio solved this for me after I restarted it.  It took the one feature with 7 list Definition and Instances and split them into **7 separate Features.**  I re-deployed and it worked.